# Why do I get permission denied when mounting drive as root?

Tags: linux, usb, permissions, mount

I am trying to mount a USB drive on my Linux computer. But whenever I try to mount it gives me this error:

```
root@penguin:~/drives# mount /dev/bus/usb/001/002 drive1
mount: /root/drives/drive1: permission denied.
```

I tried setting the permissions:

```
chmod 777 drive1
```

but it kept giving me the error.
I am using Crostini on a chromebook.
Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: You cannot use mount to directly interface with a USB device. `mount` doesn't know what USB is.  You need to find the block device name with `lsblk`, `fdisk` or `dmesg`